# "gnome-screenshot --area" not working if a select element is unfolded in Google Chrome

Tags: 18.04, gnome, google-chrome, gnome-screenshot

I am currently observing a strange behavior of Gnome Screenshot when a select element is unfolded in Google Chrome. I have searched for similar issues on this network and on other sites, but found none.

I've tried to write a reproducible example:

A select box can be found [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). This is how it looks unfolded on Google Chrome:
[image: the open select element]
(I made this screenshot by running `sleep 5; gnome-screenshot` and then cropping it to this size.)

But when I run `sleep 5; gnome-screenshot --area` the process `gnome-screenshot` "freezes" when the select box is unfolded (see picture below). It seems like it's waiting deadlock-like forever, no matter if the select is folded again or not, and it has to be terminated manually. No error is thrown, nothing in the logs. Otherwise if the select isn't unfolded, everything works fine and after 5 seconds you can select the screenshot area with the command.

I also tried it multiple times over the key shortcut, but this also leads to the same problem:
[image: top output]

For comparison: In Firefox an area screenshot is possible without any problems. However via the key combination the select folds again before the screenshot, because the Firefox window looses focus. Maybe it is important to mention that the select has the standard design of Ubuntu in Firefox and in Chrome not; [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbGpe.png).

My questions are: Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Should I report this issue somewhere?
Thanks for the help and information in advance!

---

Ubuntu: 18.04.4 LTS
gnome-screenshot: 3.25.0
Google Chrome: 83.0.4103.116